# Cisco AIR-AP1852i-E-K9 stuck in "waiting for uplink[...]" after startup

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, access-point, power-over-ethernet

I pulled an old cisco AP from a shelf today at work to test something, and after starting up and connecting with PUTTy, i was greeted with (after startup), this - repeating over and over:

```
[*02/16/2017 02:16:03.9706]
[*02/16/2017 02:16:08.9691] waiting for uplink IP address and reachable default gateway
[*02/16/2017 02:16:08.9691]
[*02/16/2017 02:16:13.9875] waiting for uplink IP address and reachable default gateway
[*02/16/2017 02:16:13.9875]
[*02/16/2017 02:16:18.9859] waiting for uplink IP address and reachable default gateway
```

I read that its a bug in the iOS, however on the bug search site on cisco it says its a bug in 8.2.111.25 - this one, however,  has active version 8.3.102.0  and backup version 8.2.111.0

Ive tried rebooting it several times, nothing changed - it is getting power through POE, if that helps - i can imagine that the error is related to that, though i do not have a normal power supply unit at hand to test it myself today.

Hope the problem is known enough that someone can help me out here, thanks in advance.

Comment: While I'm not familiar with Cisco APs, does that message mean that it's waiting for a DHCP response? Are you using DHCP? Have you tried using DHCP?

Comment: I think the issue is that its a lightweight AP that needs a WLC to run, and it seems like on this IOS version its not possible to just tell it not to wait for WLC IP info, you apparently need to flash a dedicated firmware for standalone APs to change that

Comment: Hmm, see if it has some automatic firmware download over TFTP available, you can sneak in new firmware into Cisco IP phones like that on boot-up if you supply them with the right options over DHCP, so the WAPs might work the same way.